# How can I run slider in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, slider, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My view like this :

```
@foreach($leagues as $league)
    <a @click="$refs.leagues.changeLeague({{ $league->id }})">
        {{ $league->name }}
    </a>
@endforeach
...
<top-league class="slick" league-id="{{ $league_id }}" ref="leagues"></top-league>
```

My top league component vue like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="item in items">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-image">
                    <a :href="baseUrl+'/leagues/'+item.id+'/'+item.name"
                        :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + baseUrl + '/img/leagues/'+item.photo+ ')'}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['leagueId'],
        created() {
            $('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});
            this.getTopLeague([{league_id: this.leagueId}]) // this is ajax if load first
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getListLeague'
            ]),
            items() {
                const n = ['getListLeague']
                return this[n[0]] // this is response ajax // exist 5 league
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'getTopLeague'
            ]),
            changeLeague(leagueId) {
                this.getTopLeague([{league_id: leagueId}]) // this is ajax if a link clicked     
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When loaded the first time, there are 5 items of data displayed in the form of sliders. I tried putting this code : `$('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});` in `created`, but there was an error

If the code executed, there exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: $(...).slick is not a
>   function"

How can I solve it?

Comment: Looks like you haven't imported slick in your component file.

Comment: @Roy J, If this code : `$('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});`, I copy on the console and run it, it works. But it is by component vue, it does not work. Seems because I use ajax

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this.

```
<template>
   <div ref="slick">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="item in items">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-image">
                    <a :href="baseUrl+'/leagues/'+item.id+'/'+item.name"
                        :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + baseUrl + '/img/leagues/'+item.photo+ ')'}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['leagueId'],
        mounted() {
            $(this.$el).slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});
            this.getTopLeague([{league_id: this.leagueId}]) // this is ajax if load first
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getListLeague'
            ]),
            items() {
                const n = ['getListLeague']
                return this[n[0]] // this is response ajax // exist 5 league
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'getTopLeague'
            ]),
            changeLeague(leagueId) {
                this.getTopLeague([{league_id: leagueId}]) // this is ajax if a link clicked     
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There exist error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: You need to load jQuery and Slick before your Vue instance.

Comment: I had load it. The error occurs when I run gulp watch. The error :  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. Because this code : `$(this.$refs.slick).slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});`. If I remove the code, there is no error

Comment: If I copy this code : `$('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});` on the console and run it, it works.

Comment: There exist error : `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).find(...).slick is not a function"`

Comment: Try again now, it's just not finding the element hence it throws that error

Comment: There still exist error. The error like this : `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function"`

Comment: Well, are you sure slick is loaded ? You should load jquery first then slick then your vue

Comment: Seems it had loaded. Because If I copy this code : $('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false}); on the console and run it, it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149864/discussion-between-trending-news-and-kira-san).